# Why can't I answer my own question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, self-answer

My question: [websharper for VS Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312253/websharper-for-vs-express-2012)

I wanted to answer it, but don't see the answer textbox.

Maybe rules were changed?

Comment: I checked its still there!!!

Comment: To get Textbox, you need to click on `Answer Your Question` button.

Comment: @hims056 I'd add that as an answer (with a screenshot) :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I wanted to answer it, but don't see answer's textbox.

To get the textbox/edit to answer, you need to click on the *Answer Your Question* button at the bottom of the page.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You made me click it, you sneaky devil.

Comment: yes, I don't know why I didn't see it before, it's there.

Comment: @Alex Yeah. that's experience. I also stuck a year ago to find how to answer my own question..

Comment: it's strange, because I already used it before, but completely forgot now.